# Rename JIRA project

Tags: jira

I am not referring to the project key. I know I can't change that. I need to rename a project and I can't see how to do that. I am using Jira onDemand. The project already has open and resolved issues against it.

Comment: Good question, but I think it's better suited for [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: actually, you *can* change JIRA project key, but it takes a little bit of effort and might lead to serious consequences. https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Changing+the+Project+Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change the name of the project via the Edit Project link at the top right of the project administration page.

Keep in mild that the project's issues' keys will stay the same! So if an issue was **BSRBV-100** it will still have the same unique identifier. New issues should also keep this identifier scheme.

Comment: I finally found the edit button under operation. I don't know if that's what you meant. Anyway, you get the credit.